# How do I get my code to show a certain number of characters from a text file

Tags: python

In my assignment i'm expected to look for a word and only return a set number of characters (which is 80, and 40 on each side surrounding the word), without the use of nltk or regex.

I've set my code up as so

```
open = open("a2.txt", 'r')
 file2read = open.readlines()
  name = 'word'
    for line in file2read:
        s2 = line.split ("\n", 1)
        if name in line:
           i = line.find(name)
           half = (80 - len(name) - 2) // 2
           left = line[i - half]
           right = line[i + len(word) + half]
           print(left + word + right)
```

but then my print out looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPzMJ.png)(updated screenshot) instead of the 80 character lines which i'm hoping to find.

Sorry if this is a really newbie error as i'm only 3 weeks into the program and i've been searching and can't seem to get the answer

Comment: Judging by your output, it seems that the lines are not properly split (this can happen for different reasons, one of them being the inconsistency in line breaks between Windows and Unix). Can you verify that the `file2read` contains multiple lines, and not just the whole file as one mega-long line?

Comment: the txt file does seem like chunks of texts (as shown in the screenshot)

a2.txt was a new file written from a previous file which was split based on whitespaces....could this be a possible reason for the chunk of text?

Comment: I mean, if you are splitting on whitespaces, it certainly should *not* be a reason. Again, just check the length of your `file2read` object, and verify that it is not 1.

Comment: i've checked it and it returned a length of 10,000 characters. I will look through the steps provided below and try again. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Note that a length of 10000 is then not indicating *characters*, but *lines*. Also, if you have not worked much with python before, I highly recommend using an interactive shell for the purpose of exploring your data (if you are using [Anaconda Python](http://anaconda.org), you could for example make use of Spyder, which comes with a script editor, as well as an interactive shell on the side. Good luck with your assignment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing readlines which might not be consistent due to differences in windows/Unix you can also read the entire text at once:

You don't need to separate it in lines:

```
with open('a2.txt', 'r') as file:
    a = file.read()
    name = 'word'
    if name in a:
       i = a.find(name)
       half = (80 - len(name) - 2) // 2
       left = a[i-half:i]
       right = a[i+len(name):i + len(name) + half]
       print(left + name + right)
```

This way you are reading the entire text at once. Finding your word and printing the necessary 80 characters. This is the output

```
ut. even know say trip tip sandwich. words describe it. meat eater, love it. b
```

If you want to make it work for all the words in the text. You will need to make a loop =) but that i'm sure you can figure it out by yourself!

Comment: +1 for not providing a direct solution since this is an assignment question, but still providing meaningful insight!

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. I've almost got the code out except for the last part of printing the line. I can't seem to get it out in a concordance view.  
  
My code is i = line.find(word)  
left = line[i-39]  
right = [i+40]  
print(left + word + right)

Comment: you need to add to the right not i  + 40 because i is the first character of the word. So you need to consider len(word) also in your calculation for the right side!

Comment: thanks for that tip. i've tried it but it still isn't working out. i'm not sure how to post a screenshot in the comments here though :/

Comment: edit your answer and i'll see to it! Also edit with your new code under your old one please =)

Comment: oh wait silly me i've removed my old code :/ also thank you so much for the help!

Comment: No problem! Now your problem is that you are indexing in the line but you need to index it in the whole text. Because sometimes 40 characters behind is in the previous line and 40 characters ahead might be in the next line =)

It is almost the same thing you did before.

Comment: I must have messed up my codes even more since it seems to be even worse than before haha. I think it might have to do with the split lines function. After checking len line, the answer is more than 1, but it also gives a vertical string of numbers, am I on the write track?

Comment: don't use readlines
use file.read() only that way you will have the entire file in file2read

Comment: once i've changed from readlines to just read, i get no output for my code

Comment: please join this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/178360/how-do-i-get-my-code-to-show-a-certain-number-of-characters-from-a-text-file and I will help you there!

Comment: omg i'm so sorry i just realised i don't have enough reputation to talk in the chat. are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Yes, upload the a2.txt file and link it in the comments.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19md22APpUvdJ8TWSeM948rzF7kgyMumH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: edited with answer. Sorry for having done it in iteractions instead of giving the direct answer but i figure you got a better understanding of the problem this way

Comment: thank you so much again for all the trouble!! i appreciate you going through it in iteractions, it made me think more.